# c++ heap with removing any element method

Tags: c++, heap

I am trying to implement my own heap with the method removing any number (not only the min or max) but I can't solve one problem. To write that removing function I need the pointers to the elements in my heap (to have O(logn) time of removing given element). But when I have tried do it this way:

```
vector<int*> ptr(n);
```

it of course did not work.

Maybe I should insert into my heap another class or structure containing int, but for now I would like to find any solution with int (because I have already implemented it using int)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to remove (or change the priority of) other objects than the root, a d-heap isn't necessarily the ideal data structure: the nodes keep changing their position and you need to keep track of various moves. It is doable, however. To use a heap like this you would return a handle to the newly inserted object which identifies some sort of node which stays put. Since the d-heap algorithm relies on the tree being a perfectly balanced tree, you effectively need to implement it using an array. Since these two requirements (using an array and having nodes stay put) are mutually exclusive you need to do both and have an index from the nodes into the array (so you can find the position of the object in the array) and a pointer from the array to the node (so you can update the node when the position changes). Almost certainly you don't want to move your nodes a lot, i.e. you rather accept finding the proper direction to move a nodes by searching multiple nodes, i.e. you want to use a d > 2.

There are alternative approach to implement a heap which are inherently nodes based. In particular Fibonacci heaps which yield for certain usage patterns a better amortized complexity than the usual O(ln(n)) complexity. However, they are somewhat harder to implement and the actual efficiency only pays off if you either need to change the priority of a node frequently or you have fairly large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

A *heap* is a particular sort of data structure; the elements are stored in a binary tree, and there are well-established procedures for adding or removing elements. Many implementations use an array to hold the tree nodes, and removing an element involved moving log(n) elements around. Normally the way the array is used, the children of the node at array location *n* are stored at locations *2n* and *2n+1*; element 0 is left empty.

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) does a fine job of explaining the algorithms.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to remove any element in my heap. Not the max or min. To remove any element I must be able to find it in const time and then make heapify() procedure (to keep order in heap). But the problem is to find in const time that element.

Comment: You didn't say that, you said something about not being able to remove elements, and something about using a vector. There's no way to find an arbitrary element in constant time in a heap; you can't even find one in log(n) time.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that algorithm you have in mind for maintaining a priority queue actually doesn't require the tree to be a binary tree! The algorithm works for d-heaps for other values of d than 2 as well and with the same complexity for the operations. In fact, in may cases a d bigger than 2 works better because the comparison is often cheap compared to moving objects.